# How to page thru sqlkata PaginationResult?

Tags: c#, .net-core, pagination, sqlkata

I am using .NET Core and SQLKata to access SQL Server database.
I have a method to get all records from the database using SQLKata.Execution.PaginationResult.

This is in Repository:

```
public class MyTableRepository : IMyTableRepository
{
   private QueryFactory _db;
   public MyTableRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
     var conn = new 
     SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyTable"));
     _db = new QueryFactory(conn, new SqlKata.Compilers.SqlServerCompiler());
   }

  public PaginationResult<MyModel> GetAll(int page = 0, int perPage = 25)
  {
    dbResult = _db.Query("MyTable").Paginate<MyModel>(page, perPage);
    return dbResult; 
  }
```

The above is called from my Controller like so:

```
    private readonly IMyTableRepository _MyTableRepository;
    public MyTableController(IMyTableRepository MyTableRepository)
    {
        _MyTableRepository = MyTableRepository;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetMyTable")]
    public List<MyModel> GetMyTable()
    {
        PaginationResult<MyModel> dbResult = MyTableRepository.GetAll(1, 
        25);
        List<MyModel> AccumResult = dbResult.List.ToList();
        while(dbResult.HasNext)    
        {       
            dbResult = dbResult.Next();
            AccumResult.AddRange(dbResult.List.ToList());
        }
        return AccumResult;  
    }
```

How do I get the Next set of result from dbResult ?

I tried below, after I execute GetMyTable, I execute GetNextMyTable, but in PaginationResult GetNext(), dbResult is always null.

In controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetNextMyTable")]
    public List<MyTable> GetNextMyTable()
    {
        var result = _MyTableRepository.GetNext().List;
        return result.ToList();
    }
```

In Repository:

```
public PaginationResult<MyTable> GetNext()
{
  while(dbResult.HasNext)    //--->> dbResult is null
  {       
   dbResult = dbResult.Next();
   return dbResult; 
  }      
  return null;
}
```

If I do the Next method inside the Controller, I am also getting an error

```
private readonly IMyTableRepository _MyTableRepository;
private PaginationResult<SP_SMA_Reporting_Accts> dbResult;

[HttpGet]
[Route("GetMyTable")]
public List<MyModel> GetMyTable()
{
    var dbResult = _MyTableRepository.GetAll(1, 25).List;
    return dbResult.ToList();
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("GetNextMyTable")]
public List<MyTable> GetNextMyTable()
{
    var result = dbResult.Next().List;//->Error since dbResult is null
    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: why not returning `db.Query(...).Paginate(page, perPage)` directly inside `GetAll()`, then use the `result.Next()` method

Comment: Did you mean to also do result.Next() inside GetAll() ?  dbResult = _db.Paginate<MyModel>(new Query("MyTable"), page, perPage);   dbResult.Next();  return dbResult;

Comment: Nop, just return the `PaginationResult` and use the `Next()` method in your controller

Comment: In my Controller, in GetNextSP_SMA_Reporting_Accts(), when I do var result = Result.Next().List; Result is also null, so I get an error also. I updated my original posting with this code

Answer (score 0):

In short refactor your repository method `GetAll` to call the `db.Query`

use:

```cs
_db.Query("MyTable").Paginate<MyModel>(page, perPage);
```

instead of

```cs
_db.Paginate<MyModel>(new Query("MyTable"), page, perPage);
```

**Explanation:**
when calling the `Next()` method the `PaginationResult` delegate the pagination process to the holding query, in your case since your are passing `new Query()` thus no connection info, you are getting null.

Comment: I edited GetMyTable() in the Controller in the original post. So, GetMyTable() will return all the records from the table in the List AccumResult. Is this what you meant ? How about if I only want to return 25 records at a time (this is the Pagination perPage) in the List ? And, when the calling application call GetNext() it will return the next 25 records (.Next() function). Is that possible ?